# Where are THE GLOBAL INSTALLED packages?

Tags: yarnpkg

### I have uninstalled everything

I have uninstalled chocolatey, node, npm, and yarn in windows
I have deleted the cache folder. But it still gives the same error.
WHERE ARE REST OF THE GLOBAL INSTALLED FOLDERS?
I still have lots of old globally installed packages.

[image: how to remove these]

Check out Striped version of error...

```sh
yarn global list

yarn global v1.22.0
warning Pattern ["colors@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\myUser\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-colors-1.4.0-c50491479d4c1bdaed2c9ced32cf7c7dc2360f78-integrity\\node_modules\\colors" as pattern ["colors@^1.1.2","colors@^1.1.2","colors@^1.1.2"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.

warning url-loader@1.1.2: Invalid bin field for "url-loader".

info "@vue/cli@4.2.2" has binaries:
   - vue
```

Do you have some recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yarn global dir` to discover the location.

Global installed files are under `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global`

[Check docs for a more detailed answer.](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global#defining-install-location)